# DataGridView automatic sorting doesn't work when datasource bound

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

My problem is:
when I bind datasource to DataGridView

```
BindingList<Contract> contracts = new BindingList<Contract>(Contract.GetAll());
dgEndingContracts.DataSource = contracts.Where(c => c.ExpirationDate <= nextMonth && c.IsArchived == false).ToList();
```

and set every column to `SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic`
when I click on dataGridView header rows doesn't sort.

But when I manually create each column, create and fill with data each row of dataGridView, and the set column sort mode to automatic, sorting works fine.

What is the difference and how can I enable sorting in first approach?

Comment: are the columns set to create automatically in the Grid? that's the only thing that I can think of .. it's the AuoGenerate Columns property I believe..

Comment: Setting AutoGenerateColumns to false and manually adding columns doesn't help either. I want to avoid manually creating columns and rows in DataGridView because of performance issues.

Comment: if you are manually creating the columns then it sounds to me like you will need to manually create them in code as well as using the `new` key word to create the columns if I am following what you are saying in your original question

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I 've found solution.

It's seems that DataGridView can't sort either `List <T>` or `BindingList<T>`

So I've added `class SortedBindingList<T>` based on [code from](http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/sortablebindinglist.html):
and now my `DataGridView` can sort columns.

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 2):

.ToList() doesn't return something that implements IBindingList.
Use something, like thtat:

```
dgEndingContracts.DataSource = new BindingList<Contract>(contracts.Where(c => c.ExpirationDate <= nextMonth && c.IsArchived == false).ToList());
```

Comment: Effect is the same. Click on column header doesn't sort it.

Comment: Yeah, BindingList doesn't support sorting by default. This is an example of how to make it sortable: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/22693b0e-8637-4734-973e-abbc72065969/) See implementation of SortableBindingListCollection<T> there.