# winform datagridview column sort

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to sort a column in a standard windows forms datagridview.

Visual Studio 2015
Target .net Framework: 4.5.2

I've set AllowUsersToOrderColumns to True.  All columns have SortMode set to Automatic.  My data source is a BindingList of objects.  All columns have the DataPropertyName set.  The grid loads and displays fine.  I don't see the up/down arrow and clicking the column header does nothing.  Do I have to implement some code?  I thought this was default behavior.  What am I missing please?

Thank you.

Comment: The BindingList<T> class doesn't support sorting. You'll have to derive from it and implement sorting. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.sortpropertycore?view=net-5.0#remarks).

Comment: ...or use a DataTable, which already implements all sorting / filtering / notifying / selecting stuff out of the box. Using a simple BindingList, you also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class objects (and nested custom types, eventually). Or use an ORM / mini-ORM. -- If it's not a requirement of sort, update your .Net Framework version, 4.5.2 is quite old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers above are correct.  I've also found another article that points to code that converts a list to a "SortableBindingList".  Of course you can change the class name if you like.  Look at the marked answer in

[Sortable List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439816/datagridview-automatic-sorting-doesnt-work-when-datasource-bound)